# Google sheets TEXT() formula breaking decimals

Tags: google-sheets

I've got the following numbers and their respective formatting using the TEXT() formula with `"###.###"` as a value:

| Number | Formatted | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1250 | 1250. | =TEXT(A1, "###.###") |
| 145020 | 145020. | =TEXT(A2, "###.###") |
| 1320502.221 | 1320502.221 | =TEXT(A3, "###.###") |
| 125235.1 | 125235.1 | =TEXT(A4, "###.###") |
| 1213513 | 1213513. | =TEXT(A5, "###.###") |

As you can see, the result of the formatting shows shows decimals only when needed, but the decimal marker (.) shows regardless of there are decimals numbers available or not.

*How can I make the decimals marker (.) only show if needed as well?*

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect, for example, how about `=TEXT(A1, IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A1),"."),"###","###.###"))`? In this case, when the cell value doesn't includes `.`, `"###"` can be used. But I'm not sure whether this is the result you expect. So I would like to propose this as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users. Now, I noticed that the regex is required to be modified. I apologize for this. In this case, it's `=TEXT(A1, IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A1),"\."),"###.###","###"))`. Please modify it in your actual situation when you use that.

Answer (score 0):

Solves the question, but not sure if it fits your needs:

```
=if(iserror(find(".", A1, 1)),text(A1, "#,###"), text(A1, "#,###.###"))
```

- Find looks for a decimal point in your number to be formatted, if no decimal, it gives an error
- iserror returns true if there is an error or false if not

Put together, if there is no decimal point (an error) return text format without decimal, if there is a decimal, return decimal format.

Silly question, but have to ask, why not apply built in formatting to the range?

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEXREPLACE to remove the decimal place if it's at the end of the string:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A1, "#.0%"), "\.$", "")
```

| Number | Formatted | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1250 | 1250 | `=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A1, "###.###"), "\.$", "")` |
| 145020 | 145020 | `=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A2, "###.###"), "\.$", "")` |
| 1320502.221 | 1320502.221 | `=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A3, "###.###"), "\.$", "")` |
| 125235.1 | 125235.1 | `=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A4, "###.###"), "\.$", "")` |
| 1213513 | 1213513 | `=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A5, "###.###"), "\.$", "")` |

I just used this to do the same as I wanted a % symbol after the numbers, so I used this instead: `REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\.%$", "%")`

The $ symbol is only necessary if there's a risk your original value